# How to delete zeros from matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vector, jagged-arrays

Here is my problem:

I have a `nxn` matrix in matlab. I want to delete all the zeros of this matrix and put the rows of it in vectors. For `n=4`, let say I have the following matrix:

```
A = [ 1 1 0 0
      1 2 0 0
      1 0 0 0
      1 2 1 0 ];
```

How to get the following:

```
v1 = [ 1 1 ]; 
v2 = [ 1 2 ]; 
v3 = [ 1 ]; 
v4 = [ 1 2 1 ];
```

I did the following:

```
for i = 1:size(A, 1)
    tmp = A(i, :);
    tmp(A(i, :)==0)=[];
    v{i} = tmp;
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slightly faster than [Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25531041/2586922):

```
nzv = arrayfun(@(n) nonzeros(A(n,:)), 1:size(A,1), 'uniformoutput', false);
```

### Benchmarking

#### Small matrix

```
A = randi([0 3],100,200);
repetitions = 1000;

tic
for count = 1:repetitions
  nzv =cellfun(@(x) nonzeros(x),mat2cell(A,ones(1,size(A,1)),size(A,2)),'uni',0);
end
toc

tic
for count = 1:repetitions
  nzv = arrayfun(@(n) nonzeros(A(n,:)), 1:size(A,1), 'uniformoutput', false);
end
toc

Elapsed time is 3.017757 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.025967 seconds.
```

#### Large matrix

```
A = randi([0 3],1000,2000);
repetitions = 100;

Elapsed time is 11.483947 seconds.
Elapsed time is 5.563153 seconds.
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert to a cell array such that you have a cell for each row and then use `nonzeros` for each cell, that deletes zeros and finally store them into separate variables.

**Code**

```
nzv =cellfun(@(x) nonzeros(x),mat2cell(A,ones(1,size(A,1)),size(A,2)),'uni',0)
[v1,v2,v3,v4] = nzv{:}
```