# Removing the zero elements in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have this matrix

neig1 =

```
 2     4     7     8    10     0     0
 5     6     9     0     0     0     0
```

& I want to remove the zero from it given that that the number of rows of the matrix might not be 2 (variable). Is there any direct way to do such thing ?

So it would look like this 
neig1 =

```
 2     4     7     8    10    
 5     6     9
```

Comment: Not if you want a numeric matrix as the output. This might be relevant though - http://stackoverflow.com/q/25530935/3293881

Comment: is neg1 a matrix after your operation. A matrix cant be like that. It should be rectangular

Comment: What is the output type of `neig1`? As Divakar and Anoop has pointed out, you cannot expect a numeric matrix as the output as MATLAB does not support matrices with an inconsistent amount of columns per row.  You could certainly get away with that in C/C++ but not here in MATLAB.  Can you provide some more details regarding the format?

Answer (score 0):

This can be a simple way, you might seek:

```
x = [1 2 3 0 0 0;4 5 6 7 8 0];

for ii=1:size(x,1)
X = x(ii,:);
y=X(X~=0)
end
```

The output is:

```
y =

   1   2   3

y =

   4   5   6   7   8
```

You cannot concatenate two or more vectors with different sizes into one matrix, although you can use
*cell*.